# Sharepoint - unable to open lookup list [error was 0x81020026]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Hi I am very new in sharepoint, I recently modify my code for a content type but it didn't work so, I tried with redeploying the original code which was working before but site homepage only displaying run time error now but site action and site lists are there and I was able to view them and central administration is working very well. I checked ULS and it displays below error:

```
Unable to open Lookup list '{392C8970-319B-437D-8565-3BD0232BBB86}'.[Error was 0x81020026]


System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass4.<RunWithElevatedPrivileges>b__2() 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode) 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param) 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)
```

**What I have tried:**

I tried resetting and recycling IIS server but no luck.
Getting latest version did not work also.
Application pool is active.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Try https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions